# How to replace values by labels in data.frames from spss files?

Tags: r, spss, r-haven

I have to read a sav file
I use the package `haven`

```
library(haven)
dataset<- read_sav("datafile.sav")
```

In the console I can see the labels :

[image]

```
        dput(head(voyages$portdep))
        structure(c(50422, 50299, 50299, 50299, NA, NA), label = "Port of departure", labels = c(Alicante = 10101, 
        Barcelona = 10102, Bilbao = 10103, Cadiz = 10104, Figuera = 10105, 
        Gibraltar = 10106, `La Coruña` = 10107, Santander = 10110, Seville = 10111, 
        `San Lucar` = 10112, Vigo = 10113, `Spain, port unspecified` = 10199, 
        Lagos = 10202, Lisbon = 10203, Oporto = 10204, `Ilho do Fayal` = 10205, 
        Setubal = 10206, `Portugal, port unspecified` = 10299, `Great Britain, port unspecified` = 10399, 
        Barmouth = 10401, Bideford = 10402, Birkenhead = 10403, Bristol = 10404, 
        Brixham = 10405, Broadstairs = 10406, Cawsand = 10407, Chepstow = 10408, 
        Chester = 10409, Colchester = 10410, Cowes = 10411, Dartmouth = 10412, 
        Deptford = 10413, Dover = 10414, Exeter = 10415, Folkstone = 10416, 
        Frodsham = 10417, Gainsborough = 10418, Greenwich = 10419, Guernsey = 10420, 
        Harwich = 10421, Hull = 10422, Ilfracombe = 10423, Ipswich = 10424, 
        `Isle of Man` = 10425, `Isle of Wight` = 10426, Jersey = 10427, 
        Kendal = 10428, `King's Lynn` = 10429, Lancaster = 10430, Lindale = 10431, 
        Liverpool = 10432, London = 10433, Lyme = 10434, Maryport = 10436, 
        `Milford Haven` = 10437, `New Shoreham` = 10438, `Newcastle upon Tyne` = 10439, 
        Newnham = 10440, `North Shields` = 10441, Norwich = 10443, Padstowe = 10444, 
        Parkgate = 10445, `Piel of Foulney` = 10446, Plymouth = 10447, 
        Poole = 10448, Portsery = 10449, Portsmouth = 10450, Poulton = 10451, 
        Preston = 10452, Ramsgate = 10453, Ravenglass = 10454, `River Thames` = 10455, 
        Rochester = 10456, Rotherhithe = 10457, Rye = 10458, Scarborough = 10459, 
        Sheerness = 10460, Shields = 10461, Shoreham = 10462, Sidmouth = 10463, 
        Southampton = 10464, Stockton = 10466, Stockwithe = 10467, Sunderland = 10468, 
        Teignmouth = 10469, Topsham = 10470, Torbay = 10471, Wales = 10472,
```

In html table, I have only the values :

[image]

How to replace values by labels in data.frames from spss files ?for displaying in html table ?

using sjlabelled package, I can get labels of any column :

```
library(sjlabelled)
get_labels(voyages$portdep)
```

1] "Alicante"                        "Barcelona"                       "Bilbao"                          "Cadiz"
[5] "Figuera"                         "Gibraltar"                       "La Coruña"                       "Santander"
[9] "Seville"                         "San Lucar"                       "Vigo"                            "Spain, port unspecified"
[13] "Lagos"                           "Lisbon"                          "Oporto"                          "Ilho do Fayal"
[17] "Setubal"                         "Portugal, port unspecified"      "Great Britain, port unspecified" "Barmouth"
[21] "Bideford"                        "Birkenhead"                      "Bristol"                         "Brixham"
[25] "Broadstairs"                     "Cawsand"                         "Chepstow"                        "Chester"
[29] "Colchester"                      "Cowes"                           "Dartmouth"                       "Deptford"
[33] "Dover"                           "Exeter"                          "Folkstone"                       "Frodsham"
[37] "Gainsborough"                    "Greenwich"                       "Guernsey"                        "Harwich"
[41] "Hull"                            "Ilfracombe"                      "Ipswich"                         "Isle of Man"
[45] "Isle of Wight"                   "Jersey"                          "Kendal"                          "King's Lynn"

I tried :

On a single column :

```
  dataset2 <- dataset %>% mutate(portdep = get_labels(portdep))
```

> Erreur : Column `portdep` must be length 36002 (the number of rows) or
> one, not 847

On all the dataframe :

```
  dataset2 <-  dataset %>% mutate_all(funs(get_labels(.)))
```

With the same error on first column   :

> Column xxx  must be length 36002 (the number of rows) or one, not 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `haven` package, you could try `foreign`. I used my own data `try.sav` including a variable `gender`:

```r
library(haven)
df_haven<- read_sav("try.sav")
class(df_haven$gender)
#> [1] "haven_labelled"
table(df_haven$gender)
#> 
#>    1    2 
#> 1972 2417
df_haven$gender
#> <Labelled double>: Gender
#>    [1] 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#>   [38] 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#>   [75] 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1
#> ...
#> Labels:
#>  value  label
#>      1   male
#>      2 female

library(foreign)
df_foreign<- read.spss("try.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE) 
#> re-encoding from UTF-8
class(df_foreign$gender)
#> [1] "factor"
table(df_foreign$gender)
#> 
#>   male female 
#>   1972   2417
df_foreign$gender
#>    [1] female female female male   female female female female female female
#>   [11] female female female male   female female female female female male  
#>   [21] female female female female female female male   male   male   male  
#>   [31] female female female female female female female female female female
#>   [41] male   female female male   female female female female female female
#>   [51] female female male   female female female female male   female female
#>   [61] female female female female female female female female female female
#>   [71] female female female female female female male   male   female female
#>   [81] male   female male   female male   male   female male   female male  
#>   [91] male   female female female female female male   male   female female
....
#> Levels: male female
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: great answer ! Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can get what you're looking for by using `haven::as_factor`.

Does this work?

```r
library(haven)
library(dplyr)

dataset %>% 
  mutate_all(as_factor) %>%
  head() %>%
  View()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use as_factor() from haven package.

```
library(haven)
as_factor(df_foreign$gender)
```

That should work! Good luck!